# Numpy memory usage when operations are performed

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I have a question about the memory usage of Numpy when there are operations performed on arrays. I observe that the memory usage is doubled even though it seems like it should not be necessary. For example, for the following two scripts, the second one uses almost twice the memory of the first one:

First script:

```
# ex1.py
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((10000, 10000), dtype=np.float32)
np.sum(x)
```

Second script

```
# ex2.py
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((10000, 10000), dtype=np.float32)
np.sum(x+x)  # this is just a toy operation for demonstration
```

I am checking the memory usage by running the scripts by `/usr/bin/time -v python ex[1,2].py` (on linux) and looking at maximum resident set size.

Basically, I am trying to understand what is going on here. Is this increased memory usage necessary for vectorization (if we do this in a loop, it wouldn't double the memory but would be slow)? Is this doubling of memory fundamental when there is vectorization (I think compiled languages can get away without doubling)? Is there a way to get around doubling the memory usage while performing vectorized operations with numpy?

Comment: The `x*x` is done first,and the result is passed to the `np.sum` function.  This is python.

Comment: You should consider the [`numexpr`](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/intro.html#expected-performance) library if this is an issue in some actual code you are writing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy works by computing full arrays and creating temporary arrays when needed. It does not make any lazy computation/optimizations. In your code, the overhead you see comes from the temporary `x * x` temporary array. You can avoid its creation by computing the operation **in-place** using `np.multiply(x, x, out=x)`. It not only takes less memory, it is also faster because it require less data to be transferred from/to the RAM. That being said, this means the initial value of `x` is now overwritten. If you cannot do an in-place operation then you need additional memory in Numpy. A tipical solution to reduce the overhead is to operate on chunks (packages like Xarray may help for that) . That being said, the constant overhead of Numpy will be paid for each chunks instead of the whole array and this can be a problem if chunks are too small. An alternative solution is to merge the operation using a basic loop optimized with Cython or Numba (or any compilers including JITs).

Comment: Actually, [`numexpr`](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/intro.html) is made for precisely this use-case.

Comment: Indeed, `numexpr` is a great package and also benefit from using multiple threads. That being said, the vectorization is not always as good as Numpy. The same problem sometimes also happens with Cython and Numba. A good example is the OP use-case, `ne.evaluate('x*x')`, which is slower on my 6-core machine because it make use of scalar instructions while Numpy (now) use the AVX instruction set (it was using SSE few month ago but we improved this). Still, Numexpr can outperform Numpy in more complex operations where a Numpy code would typically be memory bound.